# How to do start time and end time 24 hours time format and validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-timepicker

i am using sql server 2014.datatype for start time and end time is time(7).When saving start time as 14:00 from frontend, sql is taking as 14:00:00.While retrieving data from sql its showing 02:00PM.time picker is not working for me.I need a timepicker for these two fields and validation also. 1. Start time should not be greater than End time 2.End time should not be lesser than start time

I need  to show  the time in 24hours format
How to do start time and end time capture in field using bootstrap or jquery is also fine ?

```
                  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/download.png');?>">
    <title>Create Contract</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
 <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('/assets/demo/sam.css');?>" media="all"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<!--<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/demo/sam.js');?>"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Where's your code?  What have you tried?

Comment: @BryanElliott i dont want to use twitter  css..becoz its conflicting when am adding this css for timepicker <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: @BryanElliott is there any other option to do start and end time timepicker??Please suggest me

Comment: @BryanElliott i found that i didnt add this <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script> becoz of that only not working

Comment: becoz  i have already added this <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

Comment: @BryanElliott can u help me to do this?? waiting for you reply

Comment: It's very hard to understand your question. What exactly is not working?

Comment: time picker not showing in the field

Comment: is there any problem of using two  jquery js file??

Comment: <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

Comment: my page is conflicting when am using <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: please give me an example for start and end time picker 24 hrs format with validation

Comment: Yes, remove the bottom jquery/3.2.1, you dont need that.  Then under the `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js` script, I think you need to add some javascript to initialize the timepickers, like this:  `<script type="text/javascript">$(function () { $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker( format: 'LT' }); $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker( format: 'LT' }); }); </script>`  Sorry.. it's all on one line.  Examples here: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: Then since the `bootstrap.min.css` file is conflicting, you can remove that, and replace it with this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.min.css">`  Try that.

Comment: The examples link I gave you is the documentation and it has installing instructions, usage and examples, options, etc. Here it is again: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/  -  It should hopefully get you pointed in the right direction and help a lot. :)

Comment: if i remove jquery/3.2.1 it will affect my other codes???

Comment: from this example,start and end date is not there and its  12 hours format only..i need 24hours time format

Comment: No because in your code, you already have `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>` . It's the first `<script>` tag,

Comment: i need validation also.

Comment: <!--<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>--> thisis commented one only am  not using this initially

Comment: for me  timepicker is only working when i remove <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

Comment: for 24 hrs format, you can try changing the `format`.  something like this: `....datetimepicker( { format: HH } );`

Comment: Good luck!  As for the validation, first get the datetimepickers working how you want them, then do your best to implement validation, if you get stuck, explain exactly your problem with another separate question.  This will help tremendously to get your questions answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask